# Mageia 8 mate, after a startup problem when the system reworks Alt F2 short cut and windows right up cross lost

Tags: mate-desktop, mageia

After a problem on start, a soft was running and the system didn't start after the start page of Mageia 8. I fix this problem (Jackett.service).
After the restart, Alt F2 short cut, to open application, doesn't works anymore.
The windows borders are absent, upper right cross (to close it) doesn't appear.
I use MATE and I'm very glad to use it.
If I'm not  enough accurate, please help me.
Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.